# Not to save images in database, want to save only url

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I don't want to save images files into the database but files are saved automatically into it.

Code of model class which is being saved-

```java
    @Entity
    @Table(name="product")
    public class AddProduct {
    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="ProductID")
    private int productId;

    @Column(name="productCategoryID")
    private int productCatId;

    @Column(name="ProductName")
    private String productName;

    @Column(name="ProductStock")
    private int productStock;

    @Column(name="ProductSKU")
    private String productsku;

    @Column(name="ProductMrp")
    private long productMrp;

    @Column(name="ProductPrice")
    private long productprize;

    @Column(name="ProductMainImage")
    private String productMainImage;

    @Column(name="ProductSubImage1")
    private String productSubImage1;

    @Column(name="ProductSubImage2")
    private String productSubImage2;

    @Column(name="ProductSubImage3")
    private String productSubImage3;


    private CommonsMultipartFile file1;
    private CommonsMultipartFile file2;
    private CommonsMultipartFile file3;
    private CommonsMultipartFile file4;
    .......................setters and getters
```

Expected result - Don't want to save file1,file2,file3,file4.
Actual result - These are being saved automatically into the database.

Comment: Please elaborate your question, you have mentioned only simple persistence class.
What code you tried for images use case.?

Comment: you are creating CommonsMultipartFile as a part of you db column , so when ever you post data it will directly take your image/pdf. Try to enhance your logic more. Also, provide more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, must use transient because is a Java keyword which marks a member variable not to be serialized when it is persisted to streams of bytes.

these reference variables

```
private CommonsMultipartFile file1;
private CommonsMultipartFile file2;
private CommonsMultipartFile file3;
private CommonsMultipartFile file4;
```

should be changed. Like this

```
transient private CommonsMultipartFile file1;
transient private CommonsMultipartFile file2;
transient private CommonsMultipartFile file3;
transient private CommonsMultipartFile file4;
```

After that these will not be saved in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@Transient` annotation on the `CommonsMultipartFile` fields.

[The @Transient annotation is used to specify that a given entity attribute should not be persisted.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-transient)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it you want to store the content somewhere other than the database and make it URL addressable.  So I am not sure the accepted answer actually answers the question. 
Making the attributes transient doesn't leave you with URL addressable content.

I would give the community project [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a try.  This project was designed to do exactly what you are attempting to do, integrates very well with Spring Data and features the same opinionated programming model.

In case you are interested here is how I think you could do it (assuming Spring Boot).

Add the dependencies to your project:-

> pom.xml

```
    <!-- Java API --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API --> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Configure your file storage (Spring Content also supports S3):

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/filestore");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

Associate content with your entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="product")
    public class AddProduct {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
      @Column(name="ProductID")
      private int productId;

      ... other Spring Data fields ...

      private List<Content> contents;
   }

   @Entity
   public class Content {

      ... other required Spring Data fields ...

      @ContentId 
      private UUID contentId;

      @ContentLength 
      private Long contentLength;

      @MimeType 
      private String mimeType;
   }
```

Create a content store:

> ProductContentStore.java

```
  public interface ProductContentStore extends ContentStore<Content,UUID> {
  }
```

The `spring-content-fs` dependency will cause Spring Content to inject filesystem-based implementation of the `ProductContentStore` so you don't need to worry about implementing this yourself.  Moreover, the `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an `@Controller` implementation too that forwards HTTP requests onto the methods of the `ProductContentStore` making you content URL addressable.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based service that will use your `ProductContentStore` to retrieve (and store) content in `/path/to/your/filestore` on your server and associate that content with the relevant `AddProduct` entity.

So:

`POST /products/12345/contents -F "image=@/some/path/some/content.pdf"`

will upload `content.pdf` and associate it with AddProduct 12345.

`GET /products/12345/contents/{contentId}`

will get it again.  The REST API support range requests so HTML5 video controls will work appropriately too.

HTH